# c++11 multi-reader / multi-writer queue using atomics for object state and perpetual incremented indexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am using atomics and a circular buffer in order to implement a multi-reader threads, multi-writer threads object pool.

It is difficult to investigate because instrumenting code leads to bug vanishment !

**The model**

Producers (or writer threads) request an `Element` to the `Ring` in order to 'prepare' the element. When terminated, the writer thread changes the element state so a reader can 'consume' it. After that, the element becomes available again for writing.

Consumers (or reader threads) request an object to the Ring in order to 'read' the object. 
After 'releasing' the object, the object is in a `state::Ready` state, eg available to be consume by a reader thread.
It can fail if no object is available eg the next free object in the Ring is not on `state::Unused` state.

**The 2 classes, `Element` and `Ring`**

`Element` :

- to be written, a writer thread must successfully exchange the `_state` member from `state::Unused` to `state::LockForWrite`
- when finished, the writer thread force the state to `state::Ready` (it should be the only to handle this Element)
- to be read, a rader thread must successfully exchange the `_state` member from `state::Ready` to `state::LockForRead`
- when finished, the reader thread force the state to `state::Unused` (it should be the only to handle this Element)

Summarized :

- writers lifecycle : `state::Unused` -> `state::LockForWrite` -> `state::Ready`
- readers lifecycle : `state::Ready` -> `state::LockForRead` -> `state::Unused`

`Ring`

- has a vector of `Element` , seen as a circular buffer.
- `std::atomic<int64_t> _read, _write;` are the 2 indexes used to access the elements via :

  - `_elems[ _write % _elems.size() ]` for writers,
  - `_elems[ _read  % _elems.size() ]` for readers.

When a reader has successfully `LockForRead` an object, the `_read` index is incremented.
When a writer has successfully `LockForWrite` an object, the `_write` index is incremented.

The `main` :

We add to a vector some writers and readers threads sharing the same `Ring`. Each thread just try to get_read or get_write element and release them just after.

Based on `Element` transition everything should be fine but one can observe that the Ring at some point gets blocked like because some elements in the ring are in state `state::Ready` with a `_write  % _elems.size()` index pointing on it and symetrically, some elements in the ring are in state `state::Unused` with a `_read % _elems.size()` index pointing on it ! **Both = deadlock**.

```
#include<atomic>
#include<vector>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdint>

typedef enum : int
{
    Unused, LockForWrite, Ready,  LockForRead
}state;

class Element
{
    std::atomic<state> _state;
public:
    Element():_state(Unused){ }

    // a reader need to successfully make the transition Ready => LockForRead
    bool lock_for_read() { state s = Ready; return _state.compare_exchange_strong(s, LockForRead); }
    void unlock_read() { state s = Unused; _state.store(s); }

    // a reader need to successfully make the transition Unused => LockForWrite
    bool lock_for_write() { state s = Unused; return _state.compare_exchange_strong(s, LockForWrite); }
    void unlock_write() { state s = Ready;  _state.store(s); }
};

class Ring
{
    std::vector<Element> _elems;
    std::atomic<int64_t> _read, _write;

public:
    Ring(size_t capacity)
        : _elems(capacity), _read(0), _write(0) {}

    Element * get_for_read() {
        Element * ret = &_elems[ _read.load() % _elems.size() ];
        if (!ret->lock_for_read()) // if success, the object belongs to the caller thread as reader
            return NULL;
        _read.fetch_add(1); // success! incr _read index 
        return ret;
    }
    Element * get_for_write() {
        Element * ret = &_elems[ _write.load() % _elems.size() ];
        if (!ret->lock_for_write())// if success, the object belongs to the caller thread as writer
            return NULL;
        _write.fetch_add(1); // success! incr _write index
        return ret;
    }
    void release_read(Element* e) { e->unlock_read();}
    void release_write(Element* e) { e->unlock_write();}
};

int main()
{

    const int capacity = 10; // easy to process modulo[![enter image description here][1]][1]

    std::atomic<bool> stop=false;

    Ring ring(capacity);

    std::function<void()> writer_job = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "writer starting" << std::endl;
        Element * e;
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (!(e = ring.get_for_write())) 
                continue;
            // do some real writer job ...
            ring.release_write(e);
        }
    };
    std::function<void()> reader_job = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "reader starting" << std::endl;
        Element * e;
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (!(e = ring.get_for_read())) 
                continue;
            // do some real reader job ...
            ring.release_read(e);
        }
    };

    int nb_writers = 1;
    int nb_readers = 2;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(nb_writers + nb_readers);

    std::cout << "adding writers" << std::endl;
    while (nb_writers--)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(writer_job));

    std::cout << "adding readers" << std::endl; 
    while (nb_readers--)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(reader_job));

    // wait user key press, halt in debugger after 1 or 2 seconds
    // in order to reproduce problem and watch ring
    std::cin.get();

    stop = true;

    std::cout << "waiting all threads...\n";
    for (auto & th : threads)
        th.join();

    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

This "watch debugger screeshot" has been took pausing the program after running 1 second. As you can see, `_read` is pointing to the element 8 marked as `state::Unused` so no transition can unblock this state for this reader, except a writer but `_write` index is pointing on element 0 with state `state::Ready` !

[image: screenshot]

My question: what did I missed in this ? Structurally I am sure the sequence is correct but I am missing some atomic trick  ...

os tested : rhel5/gcc 4.1.2, rhel 7/gcc 4.8, win10/ms visual 2015, win10/mingw

Comment: Try TSAN for investigation.

Comment: Deadlocks with 1 reader as well ? If no, try with mutex on reader and start investigating from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37745305/923854) is correct about the problem: your threads can create "holes" in the sequence by reading and writing elements out-of-order if there's a delay between the read/write lock and the increment of the index.  The fix is to verify that the index has not changed between the initial read and the increment, a la:

```
class Element
{
    std::atomic<state> _state;
public:
    Element():_state(Unused){ }

    // a reader need to successfully make the transition Ready => LockForRead
    bool lock_for_read() {
        state s = Ready;
        return _state.compare_exchange_strong(s, LockForRead);
    }
    void abort_read() { _state = Ready; }
    void unlock_read() { state s = Unused; _state.store(s); }

    // a reader need to successfully make the transition Unused => LockForWrite
    bool lock_for_write() {
        state s = Unused;
        return _state.compare_exchange_strong(s, LockForWrite);
    }
    void abort_write() { _state = Unused; }
    void unlock_write() { state s = Ready;  _state.store(s); }
};

class Ring
{
    std::vector<Element> _elems;
    std::atomic<int64_t> _read, _write;

public:
    Ring(size_t capacity)
        : _elems(capacity), _read(0), _write(0) {}

    Element * get_for_read() {
        auto i = _read.load();
        Element * ret = &_elems[ i % _elems.size() ];
        if (ret->lock_for_read()) {
            // if success, the object belongs to the caller thread as reader
            if (_read.compare_exchange_strong(i, i + 1))
                return ret;
            // Woops, reading out of order.
            ret->abort_read();
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    Element * get_for_write() {
        auto i = _write.load();
        Element * ret = &_elems[ i % _elems.size() ];
        if (ret->lock_for_write()) {
            // if success, the object belongs to the caller thread as writer
            if (_write.compare_exchange_strong(i, i + 1))
                return ret;
            // Woops, writing out of order.
            ret->abort_write();
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    void release_read(Element* e) { e->unlock_read();}
    void release_write(Element* e) { e->unlock_write();}
};
```

Comment: Casey's solution seems ok, but perhaps you could simply relax read/write order, by simply not sharing _read and _write. Since you're spinning anyway when data is unavailable and the lock on Element is correctly implemented in the OP solution, having separate read/write per thread (just increment modulo size if unavailable) could help. So each thread just scans the list trying to acquire a lock. An atomic int can help count remaining tasks todo to ensure termination when all is done. Robust and efficient solutions also exist for shared task queues, e.g. http://doc.utwente.nl/93342/1/lace.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You do not have atomic section around the increment of the two shared counters _read and _write.
That looks bad to me, you could switch another element without meaning to.

Imagine this scenario, 
1 reader R1 and 1 writer W are happily cooperating.

Reader 2 executes : Element * ret = &_elems[ _read.load() % _elems.size() ];
and gets pushed off the cpu.

Now R1 and W are still playing together, so the positions of _read and _write are now arbitrary w.r.t. the element ret that R2 is pointing.

Now at some point R2 gets scheduled, and it so happens that *ret_ is readable (again possibly, R1 and W went around the block a few times).

Ouch, as you see, we will read it, and increment "_read", but _read has no relation to _ret. This creates kind of holes, elements that have not been read, but that are below _read index.

So, make critical sections to ensure that increment of _read/_write is done in the same semantic step as the actual lock.